# Akavache loss information on IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, akavache

We are using Akavache on project, in Android everything works great but on iOS we had some issue that is if we save a key value in the cache like this:

```
public async void Salvar(Login login)
{
    await BlobCache.LocalMachine.InsertObject("login", login);
}
```

BlobCache will save without erros, if i stop the debug session, and start again the debug and try do get the value using:

```
public async Task<Login> Recuperar()
{
            try
            {
                var dados = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<Login>("login");

                return dados;
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;
            }
}
```

i will get the KeyNotFoundException, i dont know why in Android works great but on iOS seeams that the database is gone after restart the app.

in my Xamarin config on Visual Studio check Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys is true and my

```
BlobCache.ApplicationName = "AppName";
```

at OnStar Method

Anyone knows what is happening? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved! the problem is that the path that Akavache is using, after creating my own path the problem is solved.

1 - Create a DependencyService that get your runtime platform path like for iOS:

```
var documentsPath =Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "..", "Library");
var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, "cache.db");
```

in your PCL init you do this:

```
BlobCache.ApplicationName = "AppName";
BlobCache.EnsureInitialized();

var local = DependencyService.Get<ILocalCache>();
var pathToCacheDbFile = local.GetPath();
CacheConfig.NormalCache = new SQLitePersistentBlobCache(pathToCacheDbFile);
```

My CacheConfig:

```
public class CacheConfig
    {
        public static bool Initialised { get; set; }

        public static IBlobCache NormalCache { get; set; }
    }
```

then you use all your caches like this:

```
public async Task<bool> Salvar(Login login)
        {
            try
            {
                await CacheConfig.NormalCache.InsertObject("login", login);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //todo
            }

            return true;
        }
```

this solution is based on other threads here.

Regards

Comment: Where did you find the path that Akavache is actually using?

Comment: @Guilherme thanks, this works. Could you please fix the link where you based your solution on.

Comment: Just wondering whether using a custom path overcomes the "may be deleted without notification to save space" issue?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this recently and for me it was because I was missing this file
https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/blob/master/src/Akavache.Sqlite3/content/AkavacheSqliteLinkerOverride.cs.pp

If anyone else comes across this issue I'd first recommend just doing what OP did and creating your own. In the end that's better but if you want to use the static ones then make sure to have a class that looks like

```c#
using System;
using Akavache.Sqlite3;

// Note: This class file is *required* for iOS to work correctly, and is 
// also a good idea for Android if you enable "Link All Assemblies".
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    [Preserve]
    public static class LinkerPreserve
    {
        static LinkerPreserve()
        {
            throw new Exception(typeof(SQLitePersistentBlobCache).FullName);
        }
    }


    public class PreserveAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

What's happening is that the resilient cache never gets swapped in and it just uses the InMemory cache by default. Which is why the data disappears on restart

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since you are stoping the process in the middle " if i stop the debug session, ", you are not shutting down the cache and then losing some data.

Take a look here: https://github.com/akavache/Akavache#shutting-down

Comment: Giusepe after InsertObject i put this code: BlobCache.Shutdown().Wait(); to force the Shutdown but the problem still happen. i think that the problem not belongs to shutdown... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only guessing, but perhaps your `Salvar` method is throwing (maybe `login` can't be serialized)? You won't really know that it is because you're not awaiting it. You can't be because it's returning `void` rather than `Task`. This is a bad practice that should be avoided wherever possible.

Change `Salvar` to return `Task` and be sure to `await` the save.

Comment: Kent i tried and unfortunately didn't works, i think that is a problem in the Akavache.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of **"Local Machine"**

**Xamarin.iOS** may remove data, stored in BlobCache.LocalMachine, to free up disk space (only if your app is not running). The locations BlobCache.UserAccount and BlobCache.Secure will be backed up to iCloud and iTunes.

**Xamarin.Android** may also start deleting data, stored in BlobCache.LocalMachine, if the system runs out of disk space. It isn't clearly specified if your app could be running while the system is cleaning this up.

There are four built-in locations that have some magic applied on some systems:

**BlobCache.LocalMachine** - Cached data. This data may get deleted without notification.

**BlobCache.UserAccount** - User settings. Some systems backup this data to the cloud.

**BlobCache.Secure** - For saving sensitive data - like credentials.

**BlobCache.InMemory** - A database, kept in memory. The data is stored for the lifetime of the app.

You should rather use

```
public async void Salvar(Login login)
{
  await BlobCache.UserAccount.InsertObject("login", login);
}
```

[Reference: Akavache Documentations]